Unable to create fork for public repository
I'm trying to fork a public repository (https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/polites) while logged in as Curlew-at-Ohdsi by logging in as Curlew-at-Ohdsi, navigating to https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/polites, and then selecting the fork button in upper right corner of the screen. The fork is not created in the Curlew-Ohdsi account and the page navigates back to https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/polites. How do I fix this?
